# Dynamically adding textviews to layout and adjusting accordingly

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, xamarin.android

I'm adding TextViews dynamically with code. Now I'm using a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation which i thought would add a new line when the textviews doesnt fit into the row. And how wrong I was.

Thing is I don't know how many rows there will be, since it depends on user input. Therefor a GridView doesn't feels right, since I can't specify the number of columns. And I don't know every size of every TextView, which might make it look bad if a TextView is very long and I want 3 TextViews per row.

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, I just wanna know the best one. Which layout should I use so when I add TextViews to it, so it makes a new row below the first one when it reaches the screen width?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve with using multiple textviews instead of just one?

Comment: The possibility of removing parts. Every textview will hold a name and user might decide to remove some names, while keeping some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
package us.simpleit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleGUI extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    LinearLayout ll;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(android.widget.LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-1));
        // ARGB: Opaque Red
        ll.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000);

        tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
        tv.setText("sample text goes here");
        // ARGB: Opaque Green
        tv.setBackgroundColor(0x5500ff00);
        ll.addView(tv);

        et = new EditText(this);
        et.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1,-2));
        et.setText("edit me please");
        // ARGB: Solid Blue
        et.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
        ll.addView(et);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Go!");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        ll.addView(btn);
        setContentView(ll);

        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Here i have taken One TextView and One EditText. Instead of that you can take two TextView or any Number of view you want.

Enjoy. :)

Comment: this is just replacing old textview with new one . how to add new textview next to old one ?

Answer (score 0):

Thing that you could do is to make your main LinearLayout with vertical orientation and many LinearLayout children with horizontal orientation
When you want to add TextView, get the last child of the main layout to know if this child can contain you new TextView. If not, then add a new LinearLayout with horizontal orientation

Comment: Also a solution, I'm going with the droid one though.